# Excluding results from a SQL query

Tags: sql

Is there a BLOCK or PREVENT command using SQL?  I would like to prevent or block specific product category from showing up in my search results on my website without completely deleting the category.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Oracle? Postgres?

Answer (score 1):

Use a `WHERE` clause.

```
SELECT {Select_List}
FROM {Table}
WHERE Category <> {Your Category}
```

Comment: No, you need to replace those with your own values. I suggest doing some reading on SQL basics at a site like [SQLZoo](http://sqlzoo.net/)